# YAML/YQ - remove sections that have sub-sections containing a particular attribute match

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to use mikefarah's `yq` to remote sections of a `yaml` file that have a sub-section with a particular attribute match.

More specifically, let's say that we have the following OpenAPI file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
protocol: https
tags:
  - description: Sample API
    name: Sample Echo API
info:
  title: UUID generator based on httpbin.org
  version: 1.0.3
paths:
  /uuid:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A UUID4.
      summary: Return a UUID4.
      tags:
        - UUID Ops
  /uuid/{uuid}:
    delete:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: uuid
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Deleted okay.
      summary: This endpoint makes no sense.
      tags:
        - UUID Ops
        - Experimental
  /delay/{delay}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: delay
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Returns a delayed response
      summary: Returns a delayed response
      tags:
        - Delayed Response  
        - Experimental
servers:
  - url: https://httpbin.org/
```

I want to remove all API endpoints with a tag of "Experimental", so basically the resulting file would be:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
protocol: https
tags:
  - description: Sample API
    name: Sample Echo API
info:
  title: UUID generator based on httpbin.org
  version: 1.0.3
paths:
  /uuid:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A UUID4.
      summary: Return a UUID4.
      tags:
        - UUID Ops
servers:
  - url: https://httpbin.org/
```

Where I'm struggling is to find the right 'level' for the `yq` command to work in this way.

As in, I know that I can *show* all tags in a few different ways:

> yq eval '.paths[]?[]?.tags?' openapi.yaml

or

> yq eval '.. | select(. == "Experimental")' openapi.yaml

But when I try something like the following to delete the parent section (i.e. the actual API block) based on the tags:

> yq eval '.paths | del(.. | select(. == "Experimental"))' openapi.yaml

or

> yq eval '.paths |= with_entries(del(select(.. | select(. == "Experimental"))) )' openapi.yaml

All it does it delete the specific `Experimental` tag, not the actual API block.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you tried openapi-filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), this was a bit tricky, but you can use `with_entries` and `contains` methods to achieve your desired result

```
yq e '
  .paths |= 
     with_entries( select( .value[].tags | contains(["Experimental"] ) | not ) )' yaml
```

Using [with_entries](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/entries#use-with_entries-to-filter-the-map), each of your map elements are converted to key/value pairs and by using a special notation as `.value[]`, you bypass the top level keys - `/uuid`, `/uuid/{uuid}` and get to apply your filter directly on the `tags`

Using [contains](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/contains#array-contains-array), we were able to filter only on the necessary object containing only `"Experimental"` and negate that condition using `not` to get your desired result.

Comment: Ah that's great, thanks @Inian. That makes more sense now :)